# Is there a tool to do the manual work of copying + pasting + replacing source code?

Tags: java, eclipse

Good afternoon all, I am writing the code for a custom array list of primitive **int**s (to avoid the overhead of boxing), an array list of primitive **byte**s, an array list of primitive **long**s, an array list of primitive **char**s, and an array list of primitive **double**s.

The code for these 5 classes are **very** similar. Basically the logic is (almost) identical. However because generics couldn't be used, there is no way to define common generic functions usable for all 5 classes (correct me if I'm wrong).

As a result, I have to duplicate the same code 5 times doing a string search replace each time. The problem comes when I have to edit the classes, because I have to do the same editing x5 times.

Now I was wondering what's the best way to maintain repeating *boilerplate code* like these?

Is there a tool that can do the manual work of copying + pasting + replacing?

(for example I could define a transforming function F() and tell the tool: for the source code of class `mypackage.IntArrayList`, apply the transformation F() onto the source code of classes `mypackage.ByteArrayList`, `mypackage.LongArrayList`, `mypackage.CharArrayList`, and `mypackage.DoubleArrayList`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to avoid the overhead of casting

I think you meant (un)boxing, not casting ; )

> Now I was wondering what's the best way to maintain repeating
>   boilerplate code like these?

Now, I know this answer is going to be frowned upon by some but...

The way the Trove API does it is simple: custom and automatic code-generation tool.

Trove is an API ofter collections based on primitives that runs around the default Java collections when used with primitives.  Comparing a Trove *TIntIntHashMap* with a (HashMap<Integer,Integer>* is not even fun.  It's shameful for the default Java API...

And they've encountered exactly the problem you're having.  And they solved it using code generation tool.

On a side-note note that *Trove* already has a TIntArrayList backed by primitives which may, or may not, already do what you're implementing now (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: Yes boxing it is, my mistake :)

Comment: Yes  that's what I'm looking for, a code generation/transformation tool. Which tool  did Trove use?

Comment: @Pacerier: I wrote *"custom"* in my answer because as far as I know Trove used its own code-generation/templating facility, but I'm not sure: it's been a long time I haven't looked at the source.  But it's all open-source so simply go download Trove and see if it's what you want (heck, you may even re-use the custom one Trove is using).

Answer (score 2):

As defined, the task seems rather complex. I doubt you will find any existing tool to do something like this.

As an alternative, consider code-generation: define a template using a single variable to represent the primitive type and generate code for all types from that. For lifecycle, make changes to the template rather then generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the tag, it sounds like you're using Eclipse. You can do a Global search and replace, although it isn't obvious. Go to the Search menu, do a search as normal, and then when you see the search results pane, right-click there and click "replace all"